# twitter widget won't validate

Tags: css, twitter, xhtml, anchor

I've read around that XHTML 4.01 does not has the data- attribute. Unfortunately my class calls for the use of XHTML. I need to embed a twitter widget and it works however the site won't validate.

```
a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/row2k" data-widget-id="654806159795183617">Tweets by @row2k</a>
```

Can anyone help assign the "data-widget-id" another way so that the widget will run as well as validate?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any entity references such as `&nbsp;` (or if you can replace them all by numeric references like `&#160;`), you can use the `<!DOCTYPE html>` header and then it will work AND validate.

By the way, there is no such thing as XHTML 4.01; You meant XHTML 1.0 surely, the equivalent of HTML 4.01.